# Connect Apache Spark to an Azure Data Lake (Gen2)

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, virtual-machine, azure-data-lake

I am working in a VM where I set up my entire Spark workspace and connected it to a Jupyter Notebook.  **This question is not regarding how to connect the Data Lake in Databricks. I am solely working in my VM.**
Now I want to connect to an Azure Data Lake Gen2 to read my files. I have installed the following versions:

- JDK 11.0.20.1
- Python 2.7.18
- Spark 3.5.0

As far as I know the versions are compatable with each other so the problem doesn't lie here.

So my question is why doesn't this work:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession`
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

# Get Sas Token
key_vault_url = "https://<<keyvault>>.vault.azure.net/"
credential = DefaultAzureCredential() 
client = SecretClient(vault_url=key_vault_url, credential=credential)
sastoken = client.get_secret(<<SAStoken>>)

# Paths to your JAR files
path_to_hadoop_azure_jar = "/opt/spark/jars/hadoop-azure-3.3.4.jar"
path_to_azure_storage_jar = "/opt/spark/jars/azure-storage-8.6.6.jar"
path_to_jetty_util_ajax_jar = "/opt/spark/jars/jetty-util-ajax-11.0.18.jar"
path_to_jetty_util_jar = "/opt/spark/jars/jetty-util-11.0.18.jar"
path_to_azure_datalake_jar = "/opt/spark/jars/hadoop-azure-datalake-3.3.6.jar"

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("AzureDataRead") \
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", path_to_hadoop_azure_jar) \
    .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", path_to_hadoop_azure_jar) \
    .config("spark.jars", f"{path_to_hadoop_azure_jar},{path_to_azure_storage_jar},{path_to_jetty_util_ajax_jar},{path_to_jetty_util_jar},{path_to_azure_datalake_jar}") \
    .config("fs.azure.sas.<<container>>.<<datalake>>.dfs.core.windows.net", sastoken) \
    .getOrCreate()

file_path = "/data/<<file>>" 

# Read example file
df = spark.read.format("csv") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .option("inferSchema", "true") \
    .load(f"wasbs://<<container>>.<<datalake>>.dfs.core.windows.net/{file_path}")

# Show the DataFrame
df.show()
```

I get the following error and as far as I understand, the main problem lies with the AzureNativeFileSystemStore Class:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o158.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.createDefaultStore(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1485)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.initialize(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3469)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:186)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I have checked the path of the jar files and the permissions they should be all correct. But apparently it still doesn't work because regardless of my jar files the code throws this error.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Change your jars to the ones below:

```py
jetty-util-ajax-9.4.48.v20220622.jar
jetty-util-9.4.48.v20220622.jar 
jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar
```

Instead of:

```py
jetty-util-ajax-11.0.18.jar
jetty-util-11.0.18.jar
```

Use:

```py
blob.core.windows.net
```

For configuring blob storage, not:

```py
dfs.core.windows.net
```

While loading, use the path below:

```py
wasbs://<container_name>@<account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/path_to_file/
```

Output:

[image]